# How to show multiple plots with big differences in y-values in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

say I want to create a figure in matplotlib. I want multiple plots, some of which values are far from the other plots. I.e. :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6.4, 6.7, 6.3, 7.5, 6.6])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [57.8, 61.7, 57.8, 57.5, 60.5])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [54.8, 53.3, 55.0, 55.2, 54.9])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5400.0, 5362.9, 5333.9, 5206.4, 5333.1])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [538167.4, 506828.5, 506889.6, 507461.0, 509221.0])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [51024218.8, 51006151.4, 50929451.5, 51382173.5, 51204708.1])
plt.savefig('help.png')
```

This is the figure corresponding to the lines above:

[image: Matplotlib figure]

However you will notice, that you can't even see most of the plots (You can maybe spot 2-3 plots) out of a total of 6. Is there a way for these lines to show up without clumping up, so that you can see each line?

Comment: Depends on your needs, you could use a twin y axis, or a logarithmic scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to put a logarithmic axis on the y-axis, such as :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6.4, 6.7, 6.3, 7.5, 6.6])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [57.8, 61.7, 57.8, 57.5, 60.5])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [54.8, 53.3, 55.0, 55.2, 54.9])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5400.0, 5362.9, 5333.9, 5206.4, 5333.1])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [538167.4, 506828.5, 506889.6, 507461.0, 509221.0])
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [51024218.8, 51006151.4, 50929451.5, 51382173.5, 51204708.1])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.savefig('help.png')
```

The result:
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

See Matplotlib Faq HowTo:

> A frequent request is to have two scales for the left and right y-axis, which is possible using twinx() (**more than two scales are not currently supported**, though it is on the wish list).

http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#multiple-y-axis-scales